# Construction of Continuous Functions, help me

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Show, if $f:X->\mathbb R$ is continuous at point $a \in X$, then it is bounded in a neighborhood of the point $a$.

That is, it exists $\delta>0$ such that $U_{\delta}=X \cap (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ or $f(U_{\delta})$ is bounded.

Help me, please

Comment: Do you know that the typical $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity at $a$ is equivalent to the condition that $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $a$ in $X$ for every open subset $f(a) \in U \subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, i didn't know that definition. @SBRJCT ¿how do i use it?

Comment: I assume that the set $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$? In fact, you can show that if $f$ has a limit at the point $a \in X$, then $f$ is bounded in some neighbourhood of the point $a$. I would also say that you should put some sort of attempt in your post so that others are better able to help you.